# bad performance of image_path in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We are using "image_path" a lot of times in one file.
In skylight.io I see that the rendering of this image_paths takes a lot of resources and a lot of time.

Does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: What is `image_path`? Where and how is it defined? What does it return?

Comment: I believe that `image_path` is some custom method, so you should provide its code if you want to get some help.

Comment: I usually prefere `asset_path('images/my_image.png')`

Comment: Image_path isn't a custom method. It is see: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_path

Answer (score 0):

Your server now handles the rendering of this image because this file might be stored on your server. This is why it takes a lot of resources because the server has to send down a lot of bytes to the client.

You should consider using an image CDN such as [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com) or [Amazon CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) or S3 if you using AWS to move this load away from your server.

Comment: It is actually no the sending, but rendering of the image_path that is the issue. (if I remove the method and put in the who url, the rendering is way faster.